# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una formula a excel con npoi?

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi

Tengo un problema al agregar formulas a Excel con npoi para empezar no me 
reconoce el `SetCellFormula()` y solo le asigno el tipo `CELLType.FORMULA` y lo 
agrega pero al abrir el archivo:

[image: Error al abrir el archivo excel]

y en la celda me aparece esto `=#N/A`

```
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal);
sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal).GetCell(33).SetCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal).GetCell(33).SetCellFormula("SUMA(A10:A20)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que evaluar la formula después de cargarla

```
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal);
sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal).GetCell(33).SetCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal).GetCell(33).SetCellFormula("SUMA(A10:A20)");
sheet.GetRow(renglonFinal).GetCell(33)..CellStyle = styleCell;

if(wb is XSSFWorkbook) {
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
} else {
    HSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
}
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780006/formula-in-excel-using-npoi)

Comment: Gracias pero ya encontré otra forma  
            Sheet isheet =  templateWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
            Row irow = isheet.GetRow(fila);
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)irow.CreateCell(columna);
            cell.SetCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
            cell.CellFormula = formula;

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los que trataron de ayudar les comparto el código que me funciono a mi

```
        Sheet isheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
        Row irow = isheet.GetRow(fila);
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)irow.CreateCell(columna);
        cell.SetCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
        cell.CellFormula = "SUM(A10:A30)";
```